# Idea error-Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I was just running the basic helloworld program, as follows:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
  }
}
```

After I typed "javac src\test.java" to compile it, and it compiled successfully, then I typed "java src\test", and it showed

```
">"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" src\test
```

Error: Could not find or load main class src\test".

So I set my path to

```
 ".;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin" and classpath to 
 ".;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar" so I think there's nothing wrong here..
```

And I don't know what's going on here... Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow this works. Thank you! But why I can't use  `java src\test`?

Comment: Because `java.exe` expects a fully qualified class name, which `src\test` isn't (it's fully qualifed name is `test`);  `java.exe` will also look for a class from the current execution context (the dir above src), so it won't find your class file (and then it checks the classpath)

Comment: And `javac.exe` doesn't  not require a fully qualified class name?

Comment: *"And javac.exe doesn't not require a fully qualified class name?"* - No ... confused yet :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
java -cp src test
```

`-cp src` tells Java to look in the `src` folder for classes. `test` is the name of the class to run.

Note that the `java` command takes a class name, **not** a file name.

Answer (score 0):

And I had such a problem. I have tried many of the decisions that concern path and others. It helped a simple solution: simply remove the jdk and reinstall it in the root directory like this: C:\Java not C:\Program Files\Java and then specify a paths like in this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)